# Removing specific items from a string after transforming it an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable, nomethoderror

So what I did below is get a number from user and shift the letters of the alphabet as that specific number. For example when str = "aby" and the num = 3 the output will be "deb". It works just fine with the letters only. But there will be punctuation marks, spaces, etc. and if I type "A by 3." as string, I reach erros such like Nomethod error.(The output should be: "D eb 3.") How can I shift the letters and leave the other ones unchanged at the same time?

p.s: Please don't write a new code for this. I just wanna solve the problem of my own code. Thank you.

```
puts "Please type a number: "
num = gets.chomp.to_i  

alp = ("a".."z").to_a  

# This is the erroneous part :
str = "aby".split("")

number_conv = str.map { |a| alp.index(a) + num}

letter_conv = number_conv.map do |e|
  if e + num < 26 
    alp[e]
  else   
    e = (e + num) % 26
    alp[e - num]
  end
end

p letter_conv.join
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code to shift characters into a function. Add a condition while shifting to ignore special characters.

In the main body, split your sentence on whitespace and pass each word to the above function.

```
def shift mystr, num
  ignore = %w{( ) ? ,}  # put all the characters you want to ignore here.
  alp = ("a".."z").to_a

  str = mystr.split("")
  
  number_conv = str.map { |a| ignore.include?(a) ? a : alp.index(a) + num}

  letter_conv = number_conv.map do |e|
    if ignore.include?(e)
      e
    elsif e + num < 26
      alp[e]
    else
      e = (e + num) % 26
      alp[e - num]
    end
  end
  letter_conv.join
end

puts "Please type a number: "
num = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Please type a string: "
str = gets.chomp
puts str.split.map {|i| shift i, num}.join(" ")
```

Comment: I do understand the logic behind the def but when str = A bc and num =  2 I reached "Bcd" instead of "B cd". It removes white spaces somehow. Why is that? (I added white space character inside of ignore array.)

Comment: btw I changed join(" ") to join("") in the last line. Otherwise it adds white space after each letter.

Comment: @elixir Sorry, I forgot to copy the last line of the function `letter_conv.join`. Edited. You'll have to revert your join("") change. It is what preserves the whitespaces.

Comment: So, letter_conv.join  converts the array into a string, and the join(" ") at the end seperates words with whitespaces. Am I getting it right?